# Continuity of Lipchitz constant of local lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be local lipschitz, which is equivalent to Lipschitz on compact sets.

That is, for any $R>0$, there exists some $L >0$ such that 
$$\sup_{|x|,|y|\le R}\dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\le L.$$

Let $L(R)$ denote the smallest constant satisfying this condition. May I know whether the function $$R\mapsto L(R)$$
is continuous on $(0,\infty)$?

I think if $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, then the map should be continuous. Is it true in general?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not. Consider piecewise linear functions. The local Lipshitz constant is the slope of the lines. If this changes with a jump, the Lipshitz constant will do so, too.